# add admin rating stars to magento products

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, javascript, css, html, ratings

how to add another rating stars to a product bay admin, nearby the customer rating stars.
this stars should be different by Magento default rating stars. i mean i want two kinds of stars to be shown for one product. one of theme for admin to put his rating and one of theme for customers.

i created an attribute with `admin_rating` attribute Code and with `global` `Scope` and `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` set to `text field` and `Input Validation for Store Owner` set to `integer number` and `admin name` set to `AdminRating`. then i assigned this attribute to `default` attribute set. then i created a product with `admin_rating` number `30`. after that i edited this file where my current ratting is:

```
app/design/frontend/fortis/default/template/review/helper/summary_nolinks.phtml
```

default `summary_nolinks.phtml` content:

```
?>
<?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <p class="rating-links">
            <a id="goto-reviews" href="#product-tabs"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></a>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <a id="goto-reviews-form" href="#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Add Your Review') ?></a>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($this->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>
    <p class="no-rating"><a id="goto-reviews-form" href="#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and i added this line under line 6 :

```
<div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_product->getAdminRating();?>%;"></div>
```

`summary_nolinks.phtml` content after making changes:

```
?>
<?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_product->getAdminRating();?>%;"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <p class="rating-links">
            <a id="goto-reviews" href="#product-tabs"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></a>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <a id="goto-reviews-form" href="#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Add Your Review') ?></a>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($this->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>
    <p class="no-rating"><a id="goto-reviews-form" href="#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> but my whole template messed up and no admin rating is showing.

Comment: this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Question carified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to create an attribute like `admin_rating` and assign it to the attribute set, then edit each product if you want different for each product OR bulk update the attributes from product grid and enter a digit for this attribute from 0 to 100, one star is equal to 20, so suppose you want 3 stars, enter value as 60 and then use the following code to get stars for each product at frontend:

```
<div class="rating-box">
 <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_product->getAdminRating();?>%;"></div>
</div>
```

you will have to edit the template file of your theme 
 `\app\design\frontend\your package \your theme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml` and place the code in it.

Note that this is the default rating method/design used by Magento, if you are using a customized one then you will have to amend it accordingly.

Comment: thanx
question renewed

Comment: the code I mentioned is for product/view.phtml not for your custom file `summary_nolinks.phtml` you need to use a product object like `$_product` is on product/view.phtml

Comment: how can i change its template because i want two ratings to show different?

Comment: and how can i put a tex or link next to this stars?

Comment: you can do it like a normal html.